# Where is/was location of Balintuger, Fife, Scotland?

Tags: 18th-century, scotland, place-names, birthplace

My 4th great grandmother [Elizabeth Doig was born/baptised on 16 May 1790 at Monimail, Fife, Scotland](http://wc.rootsweb.ancestry.com/cgi-bin/igm.cgi?op=GET&db=doigf&id=I678) and she [married John Moore on 30 Nov 1817 at Cupar, Fife, Scotland](https://familysearch.org/pal:/MM9.1.1/XTPW-ZM1).  Her parents were Robert Doig and Janet Irvine Urquart and [together they had 10 children with Elizabeth being their fourth. The second and third children were born at nearby Dunbog, the rest at Monimail.](http://wc.rootsweb.ancestry.com/cgi-bin/igm.cgi?op=GET&db=doigf&id=I659)

Her birthplace is recorded in the Scotland Census a number of times:

- 1841: "Fife, Scotland ... abt 1801"
- 1851: "Monimail, fifeshire ... abt 1793"
- 1861: "Monimail, Fife ... abt 1791"
- 1871: "Balintuger, Fifeshire ... abt 1792"

It is the last of these that I wish to ask about because I have not been able to find the location recorded through Google or any other searches.

Where precisely is/was Balintuger?  I suspect that it must be near Monimail (and/or Dunbog).

Interestingly, "Balintuger, Fifeshire" is what is recorded by Ancestry.com whereas FindMyPast simply records "Fife, Scotland".  Unfortunately, I do not have an image of the record to examine.

[Elizabeth died on 28 May 1878 at 25 Wilson's Place, Portobello, Edinburgh and her death certificate was witnessed by her son-in-law, James Stewart](http://wc.rootsweb.ancestry.com/cgi-bin/igm.cgi?op=GET&db=doigf&id=I678). She was also part of his household in 1871.  I am confident that I am dealing with the same person in all four census records.

Comment: Could the indexer have gotten it mixed up with Ballintogher in County Tipperary, Ireland (which is what Google corrects it to)?

Comment: @JanMurphy As far as I know there is no Irish connection.  I'll add details of her parents to the question.  On that 1871 Census record Elizabeth and her daughter Ann were recorded by FindMyPast as being born in Fife while her son-in-law and her grandchildren were all recorded as Midlothian.  Ancestry.com records her daughter Ann as being more precisely born in Kirkaldy, Fife.

Comment: I was wondering if the name has been pulled AWAY from its proper sound (as auto-correct can do on today's smartphones) because someone mistook the name for the Irish place and 'corrected' the placename.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the vowels out, which are always prone to mis-hearing...

And what you get is: b-l-n-t-g-r.

Which I suspect is Ballantager (also known as Ballantaggart) as mentioned at [the GenUKI Fife Gazetteer](http://www.genuki.org.uk/big/sct/FIF/gazetteer/b.htm). It's in Monimail parish, and [this page](http://www.genuki.org.uk/cgi-bin/placemaps?GR=NO297142) will take you to the map of your choice.

For questions such as this, GenUKI is always my starting point.
Others have mentioned [A Vision of Britain](http://www.visionofbritain.org.uk) as a good geographical resource. I will add [Scotlands Places](http://www.scotlandsplaces.gov.uk/search/partner/ballantager) and [National Library of Scotland Map Images](http://maps.nls.uk/index.html) as other useful points of call.

Comment: Many thanks - I think this has to be it because it sounds very similar and is only about one mile from Monimail Parish Church.

Comment: Luckily the Scotland Places link in the answer describes Ballantager as a farmhouse and steading. When using gazeteers, one must always be aware that some placenames do not apply to inhabited places. They can be rivers, mountains or other landmarks, and such placenames are usually incorrect if entered as event places.

Comment: @bgwiehle, Given that the GENUKI gazetteer is part of a specialised Genealogical reference site, it's much less prone to the problems you describe.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest Ballingry which is described in:

- [GENUKI](http://www.genuki.org.uk/big/sct/FIF/parishes/Ballingry/); and
- [Vision of Britain](http://www.visionofbritain.org.uk/place/16467)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion - I note that Ballingry is some 15 miles from Monimail so I plan to just assess it against other answers as they come in.  Did you base your suggestion on something stronger than it sharing the same two first syllables and relative proximity to Monimail?

Comment: I would also suggest Ballingry.  It has changed its name several times over the years.  At benarty.org.uk is a link to "A Parish Alphabet" which gives names similar to Balintugher dating back to 1388.

Comment: @Chenmunka That looks like a very useful resource but I think the other answer (http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/8001) has solved this one for me.